# VLC full screen playback issue 'top-left corner to bottom-right corner transparent line' on Gnome 3 running Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: gnome, video, vlc

Something really weird has been happening since i installed gnome 3. I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and on Unity video playback in fullscreen mode was fine.

When I go to full-screen every 2-4 seconds from left-top corner to right-bottom corner i have transparent line. I can not take a screen-shoot of it and it disappears when I pause video. It is really annoying while watching. I installed latest drivers from Intel site thinking that would fix the problem but it didn't

When I Maximize video playback is just fine, but when I enter full-screen ....

I did a lot of research on the Internet and I haven't found anything like this

Anyone here using GNOME 3 and Ubuntu 17.04 played full-screen video in VLC and faced the same problem? Thanks

Comment: I am facing exact same issue!!!! Did you found a solution?